# How can I customize JooQ to retry getting a connection?

Tags: database-connection, jooq

I am using JooQ with Spring-JooQ.

There is a requirement I am working on to make it so our DAO operations will retry obtaining a connection a few times, if it failed getting a connection from the DB. Our DB is good 99.9999% of the time, but sense its a sensitive operation I need to account for the edge case.

I have looked into using a customized Connection Provider, but I not finding good details on how this operation could be done or if this is the right way. Any knowledge on how this could be done, as well as good way to test this, if possible?

For the record, we are using Oracle DB with a Hikari Datasource in Java.

Comment: Why can't Hikari already do this for you?

Comment: Please emphase on this, this is a functionality of Hikari that I wasn't aware of, please explain. We would like the connection to retry if the connection is lost.

Comment: I don't know the answer. But I think if you had asked a question about what in your Hikari configuration is wrong, you might have gotten an answer by now... This doesn't look like something that needs a solution in jOOQ...